# Discord.py Banning members not in my server

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I work with a lot of partnered servers in sharing bans for anti-raiding. Normally I get a list of user_ids and a reason of ban. Then use dyno bot to ban them since dyno bot can ban members not in your server. But now that I am adding a ban log database to my bot I would like to be able to ban members that are not in my server.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    new_color = stuff
    hex_color = stuff

    if reason == None:

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Woah {ctx.author.name}, Make sure you provide a reason!", color=int(hex_color, 16))

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:

        dmban=(f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for '{reason}'.")
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name} has been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}", color=int(hex_color, 16))
        embed.add_field(name=f":newspaper: {reason}", value=f"User id: {member.id}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="User joined:", value=member.joined_at, inline=True)
        inlul = client.get_channel(channel_id)

        now = datetime.now()
        formatted_date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = ("INSERT INTO banlog(mod_name, mod_id, reason, datetime, ban_name, ban_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)")
        val = (ctx.author.name, ctx.author.id, reason, formatted_date, member.name, member.id)

        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()


        await member.send(dmban)
        await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=member_id), reason=reason)
        await inlul.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried using `await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=member_id)` which I found on a github page about using that to ban via user_id. But for me It will not ban the user but will add the ban to the database. I'm not sure if I make a var for member_id or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

Change the command to take a user id as args, then use this to locate and ban the user.

```
user = await bot.fetch_user(int(args))
    await ctx.guild.ban(user)
```